# Is it common to use informal words (quake) with formal English?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **quake** (noun): informal for earthquake. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quake)

Is it common to use informal words (quake) with formal English? or Do I misunderstand the following news articles?

> In 2004, a huge undersea **quake** off the coast of Aceh caused a tsunami that killed more than 160,000 in Indonesia. [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38245974)
>
> The 7.8-magnitude **quake**, which struck Saturday night, has killed at least 413 people, officials said Monday. More than 2,500 more were injured. [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/04/18/americas/ecuador-earthquake/index.html)

Comment: They might have wanted to make the distinction that an *earth*quake is one that happens under/near dry ground, while the one they reported happened under the sea. Note that [quake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quake) isn't marked as informal by Oxford Dictionaries.

Comment: Formality is a something that changes with time. I’m guessing there was a time when the word _phone_ was considered informal for _telephone_; the `informal` label is often shed more slowly in some dictionaries than others. This is why I continually exhort learners on this site: do not rely on a single dictionary when doing your research!  I just checked [several dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=quake&ls=a) for _quake_, most do not mention `informal` at all.

Comment: Stylistically, I would use "earthquake" the first time, and then just "quake" for subsequent appearances. "Earthquakes can be dangerous. The quake that hit Gotham killed over 2,000 and injured over 8,5000."

Comment: There's formal, informal, and slang.  You wouldn't typically find slang used in what you're calling formal English.  But I wouldn't call news reporting formal English.  In something like a scholarly paper, legal brief, or textbook, you would expect the writing to be formal and precise, and excessively polished for meaning.  The audience for news reports is the general population--people with a broad mix of education--and it benefits the media organizations for the reporting to be in simple, conversational language that people can readily absorb.